# Script: How to copy/move folders dynamically in Windows using commands

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am having a source folder which has folders (say A,B,C) that i should copy to my destination folder, But while copying if my destination folder has a folder say A, then that folder should not be copied, other two folders should be copied to the destination folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself found a solution for this.

I use `XCOPY` with the following parameters: `/D /Y /R /H /s /i`.

E.g.:

```
xcopy source destination /D /Y /R /H /s /i
```

Comment: Good job and thanks for coming back and posting your own solution! You know you can accept your own answer, don't you? Well, you do now anyway. :)